# converting StringBuilder variable to html in textview

Tags: java, android

i'm reading the textfile(html tag file) in android and i trying to convert it into html.
i'm getting  error when i **setText** in **textView**(output)..
The method setText(String, TextView.BufferType) is undefined for the type StringBuffer
how to change StringBuilder to String to get ouput...

```
String s = "";
            StringBuilder str=null;
            while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null){
                str.append(s+"/n");}
            String a=str.toString().trim();
            Spanned marked_up = Html.fromHtml(a);

            output.setText((marked_up).toString(),BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

plz help ...

Comment: I tried the same u have done but this doesnot work with android but possible with ios. Try making to different String and then Use it along .If u need help do let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try like this**. (To display HTML in the TextView Component)

```
myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(a));
```